# how to design layout button to be half one color, half other

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I need to design button for android app to be rectangle, and to be half one color, half other. In XML of course.

I have tried this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<padding
    android:left="7dp"
    android:top="15dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:bottom="15dp" />
<gradient
    android:startColor="#a241cb"
    android:endColor="#a241cb"
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="90"/>
<stroke>
    android:width="1dip"
    android:color="#a241cb" />
<corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use a 9 patch (2 pixels by 1 plus the 9 patch bounding box). Very easy to accomplish, no code needed - nor any other xml drawables.

Comment: See, this is wrong: <stroke>. You close the stroke tag before adding contents to it. Will give you errors (probably **R** won't compile at all).

Comment: @Tobor, i dont know how to do that, and i dont know what 9 patch is it

Comment: Anyway, I only see 1 color in your design. Where's the other one? So as you designed it it will fade #a241cb into #a241cb (iself). And have a border of the very same color...

Comment: A nine patch is a very convenient way to stretch an image leaving some portions unstretched. You control how the stretching takes place - It's VERY easy. And you can also have gradients (itf this was your intention, which didn't appear from your question, I deduced it from your layout)

Comment: @tobor, let's say i want to first half be black and second white and  i want to separate button horizontal...how to do that?

Comment: Very easy, give me 5 mins I'm doing that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a 9 patch like this (save it in your drawable folder as **bw_bg.9.png**):

[image]

You can get a result like this:

[image]

Example layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f00f"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bw_bg"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Don't mind the size (it's running on a Froyo 2.8 inch screen).
Also don't mind the notification (it's from another running app).

Comment: Done! Note how small the original 9 patch is... and how it's stretched in the button!

Comment: 9 patches can be soooooooo useful!! Worth stuying them in depth (they are also very easy to get understood properly).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
```

frist create background.xml in drwable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#4A225E"
        android:endColor="#4C4064"
        android:centerColor="#B4AFC5"/>
</shape>
```

and then set button backgrond its work for me

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using gradients as background.
 use this
create a new XML file under `res/drawable` folder and name it as `button_bg.xml`.
**button_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#D5DDE0"
      android:centerColor="#e7e7e8"
      android:endColor="#CFCFCF"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

now use it for your `Button` like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
```

Hope it helps. :)